# NodeJS encodeURI produces wrong result for ß

Tags: javascript, node.js, encodeuricomponent

I am using Javascript's encodeURI / encodeURIComponent to encode a string containing the german "ß"-letter.

Unfortunately nodejs encodes ß as %EF%BF%BD and not like for example Firefox does: %C3%9F

thus the server i am trying to communicate with cannot give me correct results.

Is there an option for changing how encodeURI behaves? maybe some utf-problem or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting it as an illegal character (\uFFFD) which in utf-8 is EF BF BD.

As I understand from a quick glance over this disscution http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/239f40df6036095d?pli=1 ,
there might be an issue with V8

Comment: Clicking through to the underlying V8 bug, it looks to have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked into it, but it only says that V8 does not support characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). ß is U+00DF and thus belongs to the BMP. So this isn't the same bug. I guess I'll submit a bugreport. Thanks a lot!